# Getting this warning after successfully run my selenium program. "WARNING: Connection reset java.net.SocketException: Connection reset"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
package seleniumPractice;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class ToolTip {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\m\\Documents\\xyz\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
    driver.navigate().to("https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/tooltip/");

    WebElement globe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@rel='home']"));
    String expectedTooltip = "GlobalSQA";
    String actualTooltip = globe.getAttribute("title");

    System.out.println("Actual Title of Tool Tip : " + actualTooltip);

    if (actualTooltip.equals(expectedTooltip)) {
        System.out.println("Test Case Passed");
    }
    driver.close();



  }     
}
```

I have the following versions of google chrome(102.0.5005.115) and chrome driver(102.0.5005.61).

I am using selenium-java version 4.2.1

I am using selenium-chrome-driver version 4.2.1

Comment: Exception occurs even though my browser and chrome driver are compatible versions (both are version 102). Is there anything else I can check  to avoid this exception?

Comment: I am getting this warning whenever I use driver.close();  OR   driver.quit();

Comment: I would avoid using .close()... just use quit() which should close the browser and dispose of the webdriver.  I think these type of socket errors come from the new "Bidi" interface for accessing devtools in the browser, but not real sure.  It may open a socks connection even if you don't use Bidi.  It suggests there was a pending call from the browser to the webdriver when you called quit().  (so browser shuts down before it sends something or other back to the webdriver/selenium localhost)

Answer (score 1):

Problem got resolved by giving quit(); instead of close();

No need to give try{ } and finally{ }.

One more thing to make sure that you should have same versions of chrome browser and  chrome-WebDriver.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `try { }` `finally { }` clause, where we don't care as much what happens after you've completed a successful test. I'll take your code and show you what that could look like.

```
package seleniumPractice;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class ToolTip {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
    try {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\m\\Documents\\xyz\\WebDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
        driver.navigate().to("https://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/tooltip/");

        WebElement globe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@rel='home']"));
        String expectedTooltip = "GlobalSQA";
        String actualTooltip = globe.getAttribute("title");

        System.out.println("Actual Title of Tool Tip : " + actualTooltip);

        if (actualTooltip.equals(expectedTooltip)) {
            System.out.println("Test Case Passed");
        }
    }
    finally{
        driver.quit();
    }

  }     
}
```